# An image from URL won't show on the tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My code works to a certain degree, the placeholder for the image shows up at the correct size, but the image itself won't show up on my page.

I'm trying to sort out sizings of these images that come from a news API

```
self.nlbl_news_one = Label(self.fr_news, text="1.", font=DATA_FONT)
self.nlbl_headline_one = Label(self.fr_news, wraplength=350, justify="left", font=DATA_FONT)
self.nlbl_image_one = Label(self.fr_news)
self.nbut_link_one = Button(self.fr_news, text="link", font=URL_FONT, 
                            command=lambda: self.headline_one(data)).grid(row=2, column=3)
self.nlbl_news_one.grid(row=2, column=0)
self.nlbl_headline_one.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=15, pady=7)
self.nlbl_image_one.grid(row=2, column=2)

self.nlbl_image_one.config(image=self.import_image(str(data["articles"][0]["urlToImage"]))


def import_image(self, url):
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve

    fd = urlretrieve(url, "image")
    img = Image.open("image")
    img_small = img.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_small)
```

This is part of a much larger block of code, but these are the lines that tie in together. I'm just confused at how I can't see the image, yet the placeholder appears.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
self.nlbl_image_one.config(image=self.import_image(str(data["articles"][0]["urlToImage"]))
```

to:

```
img = self.import_image(str(data["articles"][0]["urlToImage"]))
self.nlbl_image_one.config(image = img)
self.nlbl_image_one.image = img
```

You need to do this to avoid the garbage collection from deleting the image.

Comment: Thank you so much, the image is now actually coming up now.